# How to use ase gui to visualize the geometry optimization (through graphs and animation)?

Tags: atomic-simulation-environment

How can I visualize the geometry optimization? I want to see the plot of potential energy through various iterations to reach the minimum value. I would also like to see the animation of the atoms being moved. I have here an example code for geometry optimization. Can someone help me with the visualization?

```
import ase.io
import ase.build
from ase.visualize import view
from ase.optimize import BFGS
import numpy as np
from ase.calculators.emt import EMT

water = ase.build.molecule('H2O',calculator=EMT())
opt = BFGS(water,trajectory ='H2O.traj')
opt.run(fmax=0.05)
```

And this was the result:

```
     Step     Time          Energy         fmax

BFGS:    0 12:18:19        2.619811        7.7384
BFGS:    1 12:18:19        1.912906        1.3454
BFGS:    2 12:18:19        1.882033        0.4035
BFGS:    3 12:18:19        1.879275        0.0317
```

In the documentation i read that ase gui can do this. But i tried it in this way:

```
ase gui H2O.traj
```

However i am getting an error: Invalid syntax

Comment: Where do you type that line: "ase gui H2O.traj" ? Could you attach the whole error message with the command that couses it?

Comment: @user36313 I typed it in the command prompt. This line 'ase gui H2O.traj' i typed right after the calculation in the command prompt. Is it wrong?

Comment: Was it a Python or a shell prompt?  Because the error doesn't look like a shell error

Comment: I am new to python. So i opened command prompt using cmd. And then i typed python and hit enter and did the above mentioned activities. So i am assuming this is python now and not shell prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ase gui` command is a shell command. So you should type it not to the Python prompt (usually looks like `>>>` ), but to the shell prompt (may look like `C:\>` ). If you prefer to run visualizer directly from Python, then you should add to your code something like this:

```
traj = ase.io.read('H2O.traj', index=':')
view(traj)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now!